# Not able to load pepper plugin

Tags: c++, google-chrome, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I have implemented a plugin using google PPAPI and compiled it with ppapi toolchain to get a dll file for the same. (Not compiled with native client toolchain)

I am trying to load the plugin in google chrome browser. for that i have used embed tag in html file. i put the html file and dll file both in local host in same location (apache server). while accessing local host from browser i an seeing the webpage but plugin is not loading.

Do i need to enable/disable any flag? i made native client enable. do the dll file (plugin) will be in different location?

Please help me. i am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Running a plugin in Chrome":
http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/pepper-plugin-implementation
You need to use the --register-pepper-plugins command-line flag.

Note that:

1. Running .dll plugins is not a supported way to ship to Chrome users. It's fine for testing, but to ship your plugin to users, you need to use the NaCl or PNaCl toolchain.
2. It doesn't really make sense to put your .dll file with the server. The server has no use for it; it's only for use by Chrome. There's no viable way to make Chrome download a .dll and load it; it needs to be available to Chrome at the time that you start up.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

If i am not wrong there are 5 tool-chains available in "Native Client SDK". 

PNaCl - for pexe,
NaCl32 - for nexe,
NaCl64 - for nexe,
NaClRAM - for nexe,
one more is PPAPI - What is the use of it and how to use this Toochain?

Your comment will be really helpful.